# Track start and end position of seek in mediaelement [UWP]

Tags: c#, uwp, uwp-xaml

I have a XAML based Windows 10 UWP application which uses a `MediaElement` to play videos. For analytics purpose, when a user plays a video, I want to track the start and end positions of a seek operation.

The only event I can find is `SeekCompleted`, in which I can get the end position using `mediaElement.Position` but I can't see any way to identify the start position. Also `CurrentStateChanged` event is not fired when the seek operation starts. How do I get the start position?

Code that I am using:

```
mediaElement.CurrentStateChanged += MediaElement_StateChanged;
mediaElement.SeekCompleted += MediaElement_SeekCompleted;

//Play the video
var mediaSource = MediaSource.CreateFromUri(new Uri(streamUrl));
var mediaPlaybackItem = new MediaPlaybackItem(mediaSource);
mediaElement.SetPlaybackSource(mediaSource);

public void MediaElement_StateChanged(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var mediaElement = sender as MediaElement;
    var state = mediaElement.CurrentState;
    var position = mediaElement.Position; 
}

public void MediaElement_SeekCompleted(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var position = mediaElement.Position; 
}
```

Both methods get called only after the seek operation is completed and so I can get only the end position. I need the start position as well.

Comment: Can you add your sourcecode. Because `CurrentStateChanged` is firing for me. From that you can get start position using `mediaElement.Position`

Comment: @Archana: I have added the code I am using. But there isn't much in it. This gives only the end position and not the start position. Am I missing something here?

Comment: Where are you start playing the music?

Comment: @Archana: I play the video on the click of a button. I have included that piece of code as well

Comment: Hope you are calling play() method. When you start playing `CurrentStateChanged ` event  should trigger. Is it atleast triggering when you pause the music?

Comment: @Archana: Yes. The event is getting triggered when I start playing, pause/resume and even when the video buffers. But when I seek, it fires only if new content is not yet buffered. And even then, it fires only after the seek is complete. So I get only the end position. I need the position from where the seek was started as well.

Comment: Have you tried `BufferingProgressChanged` ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/137443/discussion-between-ferdin-and-archana).

Answer (score 0):

The default transport controls do not raise any event when you start seeking. To get this you could modify them so that such an event is raised.

There's documentation on customizing the transport controls at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/controls-and-patterns/custom-transport-controls
These show how to get programmatic access to the `Slider` used for seeking. You could add a handler for a suitable event (perhaps `DragStarting`, `Holding`, or `ManipulationStarted`?) and then record the current position then.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I tried the same but DragStarting, Holding, and ManipulationStarted don't get called when seeking. The only event I could find was ValueChanged which gives both start and end position. But this event gets called even while the video is playing. How do i differentiate seeking from video play?

Comment: @Ferdin can you combine ValueChanged and Touch Up/Down events to get your logic?